# How to apply counter while creating AMI image

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

I am writing the script to create images of the running instances and the instance have the tags of Retention Count and Frequency then the value will be picked from that running instance otherwise it will set the default value provided. Number of images created will depend on frequency.

[image]

but I am getting this output.
[image]

I have set the Frequency to in the script and I have applied the counter but instead of incrementing the value of count, it is giving the same value. For now the retention count may be dropped as I am not using this till now.

Comment: Can you add the actual code and error instead of images..?

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto 
import time 
from boto import ec2
connection = ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
count=0
reservations = connection.get_all_reservations(filters={ "tag-key" : "Automatic Backup" , "tag-value" : "True"})
A='Retention Count'
B='Frequency'
for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation.instances:
            instance_tag=instance.tags
            try:
                rc=instance_tag[A];
            except:
                rc=30
            try:
                fq=instance_tags[B];
            except:
                fq=1    
            ID=instance.id
               if fq <= '2':
                    curdate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
                    curtime=time.strftime("%H/%I/%M")
                    all_ami=connection.get_all_images(owners="xxxxxxxx")
                    for img in all_ami:
                        print img
                        val=img.description.find(curdate)
                        if val>0:
                            if count <= fq:
                                count=count+1
                                print count
                                connection.create_image(ID , name=ID+curdate+str(curtime), description=ID+curdate)
                                print "ami created"

                        if val < '0':
                            print count 
                            connection.create_image(ID , name=ID+curdate+str(curtime), description=ID+curdate)
```